# How can I use BeautifulSoup to scrape this table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and learning data analysis. I am trying to scrape data from this web page: https://bitinfocharts.com/dogecoin/address/DN5Hp2kCkvCsdwr5SPmwHpiJgjKnC5wcT7

I am able to scrape data with simple websites but I think since BitInfoCharts has tables it may be a more complex HTML setup than the tutorials I am following.

My goal is to scrape the data from the table which includes Block, Time, Amount, Balance, ect and have it in a csv file. I previously tried using pandas but found that it was difficult to select the data I want from the HTML.

To do this, I think that what I need to do is get the header/table information from the "class="table abtb tablesorter tablesorter-default" and then pull all of the information from each object inside that class that contains "class="trb". The class=trb changes from page to page (Example, one person may have 7 transactions, and another may have 40). I am not exactly sure though as this is new territory for me.

I would really appreciate any help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
url = 'https://bitinfocharts.com/dogecoin/address/DN5Hp2kCkvCsdwr5SPmwHpiJgjKnC5wcT7'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs(r.content)

table = soup.find_all("table_maina")
print(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do decide to do it manually, this does the same thing:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
url = 'https://bitinfocharts.com/dogecoin/address/DN5Hp2kCkvCsdwr5SPmwHpiJgjKnC5wcT7'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find(id="table_maina")
headers = []
datarows = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    heads = row.find_all('th')
    if heads:
        headers = [th.text for th in heads]
    else:
        datarows.append( [td.text for td in row.find_all('td')] )
        
fcsv = csv.writer( open('x.csv','w',newline=''))
fcsv.writerow(headers)
fcsv.writerows(datarows)
```

Comment: Hey that worked! Thank you so much. I'll be running this script on multiple addresses, so having the .csv file named the crypto address would help organization. Is it possible to make the CSV file name a variable which is the crypto address? I have tried this before by assigning a variable to the crypto address and then adding the variable as the .csv file name in write.csv but it would give errors.

Comment: It's just a string.  As long as you can construct a string that is a proper file name, you can pass it to `open`.  The URL is not a proper file name.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one table element called '*table_maina*' so you should call find() vs find_all(). Also, you need you specify the "table" tag as first argument in find() function.

Try:

```python
table = soup.find('table', id='table_maina')
for tr in table.find_all('tr', class_='trb'):
  print(tr.text)
```

**Output:**

```
4066317 2022-01-17 15:41:22 UTC2022-01-17 15:41:22 UTC-33,000,000 DOGE (5,524,731.65 USD)220,000,005.04121223 DOGE$36,831,545 @ $0.167$-28,974,248
4063353 2022-01-15 11:04:46 UTC2022-01-15 11:04:46 UTC+4,000,000 DOGE (759,634.87 USD)253,000,005.04121223 DOGE$48,046,907 @ $0.19$-23,283,618
...
```

Next, to output each row into CSV file then try this:

```python
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://bitinfocharts.com/dogecoin/address/DN5Hp2kCkvCsdwr5SPmwHpiJgjKnC5wcT7'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table", id='table_maina')
with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fout)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Block', 'Time', 'Amount', 'Balance', 'Price', 'Profit'])
    for tr in table.find_all('tr', class_='trb'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        csv_writer.writerow([x.text for x in tds])
```

**Output:**

```
Block,Time,Amount,Balance,Price,Profit
4066317 2022-01-17 15:41:22 UTC,2022-01-17 15:41:22 UTC,"-33,000,000 DOGE (5,524,731.65 USD)","220,000,005.04121223 DOGE","$36,831,545 @ $0.167","$-28,974,248"
...
```